# Where is this second definition of dwija written in Hindu scriptures?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, puranas, manu-smriti

There are two definitions of the word "dwija" that I know.

1. Men of Brahmin , Kshatriya and Vaishya caste are dwija.
2. Men who become alive again after dying once are called dwija. This is the reason why seers before being initiated into any sect have to do their "Pinda- Daan" or "Shraadh" which indicates that they have died .

I think the concept of dying here means men who have killed all their worldly desires or may be they really die by removing their soul from their body and then re-enter their body.(not sure about this).

Where is the second definition of dwija written in Hindu scriptures ?

Comment: A dvija means twice born

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Dvija* means twice born. Brahmins, kshatriyas and Vaishya are called twice borns because they are initiated with sacred thread.

> Yājñavalkya (1. 39).—‘For the first time, the Brāhmaṇa, the Kṣatriya and the Vaiśya are born from their mother; for the second time, out of the girdle-tying Rite (of Upanayana); **it is for this reason that they have been declared to be twice-born.’**

> Manu(2:169).According to the directions of the Revealed Word, **the first birth of the twice-born man is from the mother, the second, after the Ggirdle-tying ceremony**, and the third, after sacrificial initiation